# How to Remove "Relative Item" from alert notification send by a task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, tasks, task-list

I enabled the alert notification for SharePoint 2010 task list. But in the notification Email i am getting "Related Items" link in the json format. I don't want to show that in the email notification. But i want the Related Item field in the Task list.

Please let me know how to do this..?